# What are Google Sites Shared with me and where to view them?

Tags: google-classic-sites, google-dashboard

I've recently checked my Google Account details on the [Google Dashboard](https://www.google.com/settings/dashboard?hl=en) site.

The paragraph "Sites" told me that I have one Site and over 700 thousand sites "shared with me"
[image: My Sites: 1 and Shared with me: 700.000+]

What are those "Shared with me" sites? How can I view them?

Comment: If it's any consolation, there are 708,251 shared with me, and I'm similarly bewildered.    Suspect the count is a Google-bug, or perhaps a count of all Sites shared with the public

Comment: I've got more than 2.6 million - wasn't sure if spam or... simply useless information

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/sites/sI0imXuDsCw), [this](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/sites/OyLLra1CUnA/discussion) and [this](https://plus.google.com/105201176373156907412/posts/HbdYvgAPgHn) sources, the number is/was a bug.

As per what it means, here is the official explanation:

> #### Share your site with other people
>
> If your site is private, you can share your site to allow individual people to view or edit your site. If your site is public, your site will already be viewable by anyone, but you can share your site to allow other people to edit your site.

[Source](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/97934?hl=en&ref_topic=1046513).